# Given a traffic matrix $A$ what does it mean for the pair-wise dot products of rows to be non-zero, and can we enforce this somehow?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

The traffic matrix $A$ encompasses the information regarding the paths of origin-destination nodes in a directed graph. Columns represent od-pairs and rows the directed edges of the underlying graph. The element $(i, j)$ in the matrix is one if the edge $i$ belongs to the (directed) path in the od-pair $j$, and otherwise it is zero. Paths for the od-pairs chosen are arbitrary. That is, we can and we will leave out some of the paths. For example in the directed $K_3$ the path between nodes $1$ and $2$ could be $(1, 2)$ or $(1, 3), (3, 2)$.

What I would like to know is that what do we know about such matrix $A$ that satisfy the following property: the pair-wise dot products of the rows are non-zero. In other words, each pair of rows has at least one common column full of ones.

So, how could we talk about this in the language of graph theory/linear algebra/lattices and, does this question result in a decision problem. Specifically, if we want to enforce the aforementioned property, do we have an algorithm to reformulate the matrix $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property means that every pair of edges has a common od-pair.  That is, for all $i_1$ and $i_2$ with $i_1<i_2$, there exists at least one $j$ with both edges $i_1$ and $i_2$ in the path for od-pair $j$.

Comment: Is there a term in graph theory to characterize such edges that do not have any common path?

Comment: Not that I know of. But even if there is, failure of the property here would still allow the possibility that a different path (instead of the chosen one) for some od-pair could contain both edges.